# Find Previous month name using Calender or any classes that in java

Tags: java, datetime, date

I need to Find Previous month name using Calender or any classes that in java

if its January then its must give December as previous month (with year if possible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
//format it to MMM-yyyy // January-2012
String previousMonthYear  = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-yyyy").format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: You could accept the answer since it does answer your question well :)

Answer (score 0):

JODA rocks.

Get it from http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime year2000 = dt.withYear(2000);
DateTime oneMonthBefore = dt.minusMonths(1);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = ...;
String d = dt.toString(fmt);
```

It's way easier to use and manipulate date/times than anything in the java library.